# Changing rendered fonts to PT Sans

Tags: html, css

I'm using Visual Studio and for some reason my rendered font  is showing as Arial, even tho I set the font-family to `font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;`

Why is this? 
This is not because of the browser because I checked it with every browser and it's the same. 
How can I change the rendered font to 'PT Sans'?

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle ?

Comment: Either PT Sans is not available to the browser, your HTML doesn't contain any characters that appear in the font, or something else is wrong that isn't possible to determine with the incomplete test case you've provided.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud — Stackoverflow has supported [inline, live demos](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year. There's no need to host html/css/js demos on third party services.

Comment: @Quentin Most of people here say "fiddle" as a generic noun. We don't care if it's on Stack, JSFiddle or Codepen, we just want all the informations to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in the `head` element of your page:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**Alternatively**, you could add this inside a CSS file that's already loaded by the page:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
```

You can also customize the character sets and the styles being loaded in [this page](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:PT+Sans). Select your desired character set(s) and style(s) and use the resulting link.